# Is it possible to customize the options in the Shutdown Event Tracker?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I want a more specific classification in the Shutdown Event Tracker, such as 'Windows Update' instead of 'Application Maintenance'.  Of course the 'comments' field are always available, but I'm not willing to repeat myself every time.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Modify this registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Reliability\UserDefined
```

Look for a value named `ShutdownReasonUI`. If it's not there, create a DWORD value key with that name. Add your custom reasons.

***BUT ADDING REGISTRY KEYS IS SCARY!***

Yes, and you should be careful. [However it's an old trick (search for ShutdownReasonUI)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778526(v=ws.10).aspx#w2k3tr_set_tools_xocg), and should still work to this day. [Here's the sparse documentation about the key itself](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779101(v=ws.10).aspx). YMMV.

Comment: Searched with the registry key and got detailed instructions [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/202941/disabling-windows-2003-2008-reason-for-shutdown-dialog). Thanks.

Comment: By the way, a MULTI_SZ is needed rather than a DWORD.